# MongoDb groupby count query

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql-aggregation

[image]
I have a mongoDB document having certain columns like  Id, EmployeeID, SiteID, EmployeeAddress.
A employee can be present at a site more than once.
I want to have a group by query along with count which will give result set as

EmployeeID SiteID Count EmployeeAddress

basically how many times an employee is present as a site.
I am using this query but not getting the desired data.

```
  db.pnr_dashboard.aggregate(
[
{ 
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : { "siteId" : "$siteId" , "employeeId" : "$employeeId"} , 
        "count" : { "$sum":1}},


} 
]
);
```

Comment: Could you show sample document from `pnr_dashboard` collection ?

Comment: @mickl sample document attached

Comment: Thanks. There is not `employeeId` in your doc but you're trying to group by that field. Is that ok ?

Comment: EmployeeId is there but as some records do not have the employee id so in the JSON it is not present

Comment: put your sample collection instead of screen shots and your query seems to be ok